# add string to calculated output in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am using a line of PowerShell to check RAM on a machine and it works great but I need to add a string to the output:

```
Get-CimInstance -class Win32_PhysicalMemory |
  Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum |
    % {[Math]::Round(($_.sum / 1GB),2)}
```

This produces a result based on how much memory the machine has but I need to add "GB" to the end so the output is 16GB not just 16.

I have tried various things, none has worked. I guess I am struggling to understand how to add a string to the output of a calculated property.

Answer (score 1):

(a) Use an **expandable string** (string interpolation):

```
Get-CimInstance -class Win32_PhysicalMemory | 
  Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum | 
    % { "$([Math]::Round($_.sum / 1GB,2))GB" }
```

You can use `$(...)`, the subexpression operator, to embed expressions and even multiple statements in a double-quoted string.

---

(b) Alternatively, use .NET string formatting via the **`-f` operator**:

```
Get-CimInstance -class Win32_PhysicalMemory | 
  Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum | 
    % { '{0:G2}GB' -f ($_.sum / 1GB) }
```

The format string on the LHS must contain a placeholder for each RHS argument, starting with `{0}`; optionally, formatting instructions can be embedded in each placeholder, which in this case performs the desired rounding and displays up to 2 decimal places (`G2`).
The `-f` operator uses .NET's [`String.Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2#Starting) method behind the scenes.

---

**Important**:

- Method (a) always uses the *invariant* culture, in which `.` is the decimal mark.
- Method (b) is *culture-sensitive*, so it uses the *current* culture's decimal mark (use `Get-Culture` to determine the current culture).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .ToString() Method and then add the GB

```
(Get-CimInstance -class Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum | % {[Math]::Round(($_.sum / 1GB),2)}).ToString() + " GB"
```

hope its helps